# output keep in the same column ignoring "-" (negative)

Tags: c

This is the output I expect

```
  x        |x|
  1.2       1.2
 -2.3       2.3
  3.4       3.4
```

but I keep getting this:

```
  x        |x|
  1.2       1.2
  -2.3       2.3
  3.4       3.4
```

Here is my part of code:

```
  printf("  x        |x|\n");
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
          printf("  %.1f       %.1f\n", array[i], array1[i]);
  }
```

how do I change it?

Comment: `"% .1f"`.  [Seriously.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a number before dot in %.1f that shows all the number including '-' for example:

```
printf("%3.1f",array[i]);
```

Will result in :

```
 x             |x|
 1.2           1.2 
-2.3           2.3
 3.4           3.4
```

It means that a number should fill 3 places in screen.
Sorry for bad English.